# A Borel measurable function which is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to find a example of Borel measurable function which is not continuous.
I think that it is a simple or step function or semicontinuous function.
Please help me for find it.

Thanks.

Comment: You already mention some in your post. What else do you want?

Comment: An "even less" continuous example would be the characteristic function of the rationals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indicator function on $\mathbb Q$ is borel measurable but is nowhere continuous.